# Work Done on a rotating body

Tags: energy, rotational-dynamics, work

Hello so I am having an issue with a question I am trying to solve.

[image]

So far I have learnt that the work done by a force $F$ is equal to $F$ multiplied by $x$ where $x$ is the displacement in the direction of the force. Also, I think that it should not matter in the case of having 2 forces acting on an object if you find the work done by each force separately and then add together or add the forces together then do it that way.
Here I have tried to find the net $F$ by doing $0.12$ + $-0.12$ and ended up with $0$N, which when multiplied by any displacement leads to a work done of $0J$, but that is not the correct answer, could someone help please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Work in general is indeed force $F$ times displacement $d$ with the formula (for constant force and one-dimensional movement):

$$W=F\cdot d\,.$$

Work will indeed cancel out, when negative and positive work is done simultaneously on an object. In your scenario, though, work does *not* cancel out, because the forces at the top and at the bottom of the rotating wheel push *in different particles* of the wheel. Those particles *do move along with the force direction* in both cases, so in both cases positive work is done on those particles.

Thus, the above formula should be considered a formula for *linear* (translational) work. We can develop an equivalent formula that encompasses the work done on every particle of a rotating body to express *rotational* (angular) work. Such angular work formula is (for constant torque):

$$W=\tau\cdot \theta\,.$$

(You can derive it fairly easily in the simple, one-dimensional case with a constant force by merging $\tau=r\cdot F$ and $d=r\cdot\theta$ with the linear work formula.)

So, consider the torque $\tau$ that a force produces on the wheel. This can be thought of as a "rotational equivalent of force". Multiply this with the "rotational equivalent of displacement", that being the displaced angle $\theta$, and then you have what you need to compute the angular work done.

You might find that there is no net linear work done even though a non-zero *angular* work is being done simultaneously.

Comment: How do I find $\theta$ I have not covered angular stuff yet?

Comment: @NavBhatthal You are actually being told the angle $\theta$ in the last line of the question text with the words "*one revolution*". A full revolution would be an angle of $2\pi\,.$

Comment: @NavBhatthal The angle $\theta$ here is in radians.

Comment: Thank you for the help with the question, now when you say "rotational equivalent", what exactly is the difference between torque and force?

Comment: @NavBhatthal Intuitively speaking, force is a "push" that tries to make objects move. Equivalently, torque is a push that tries to makes things *spin*. A force pulling in a particle of the wheel will translate to a torque trying to make the wheel spin. The formula is: $$\tau=r\cdot F\,.$$ Think of turning af nut with a wrench. You pull with a force $F$ in the handle, but the farther out you pull, the easier it is - the closer to the nut you pull, the tougher it is to turn it. That is why the distance $r$ from rotational centre to where the force is exerted is involved.

Answer (score 0):

The velocities are in opposite directions, so the work-rate is the *sum* $(0.12+0.12)\omega r$ rather than the difference.

Comment: is the net force $0$?

Comment: The net force ${\bf F}_1+{\bf F}_2$ is zero, but work-rate  is $ {\bf F}_1 \cdot {\bf v}_1+ {\bf F}_2 \cdot {\bf v}_2$ is not zero because ${\bf v}_1=- {\bf v}_2$